# How to display ACF values in the front-page in index.php

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Hi Guys my name is Fotis and i am a junior web developer.

The reason i need your help is because i am trying to create this gallery http://www.elliotcondon.com/creating-an-image-gallery-with-advanced-custom-fields/ and i am using custom fields and the add on repeater.

But i can’t see anything on my browser and in my home page.But when i create anotherpage template without beign declared as front page or page for posts it works fine. So the question is what should i include in my code to make this happen.?

Please anyone who know to help me

Thank you for reading my request!

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="content">
<div id="main">
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; else: endif; ?>
<?php query_posts('category_name='.get_the_title().'&post_status=publish,future');?>
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
    <p><?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; else: endif; ?>
<!-- Slider -->
    <?php if(get_field('images')): ?>
    <div id="slider">
        <?php while(the_repeater_field('images')): ?>
            <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_sub_field('image'), 'full'); ?>
            <?php $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_sub_field('image'), 'thumbnail'); ?>
            <img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" alt="<?php  the_sub_field('title');?>" rel="<?php echo $thumb[0]; ?>" />
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>


</div>
</div>
```

Comment: When rendering the front page, WordPress searches for a few templates in the following order: `front-page.php --> home.php --> index.php`. Do you have any of those other templates? If so, they may be loading first.

Comment: I have one index.php page for the posts page and into the index.php code i have added the code. But when i make one other page without declaring as posts page it works fine.Posts-Page->Index.php